# error while installing gem json in ubuntu, ruby 2.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

When I give bundle install i got error "Make sure gem install json -v 1.8.3 succeeds".

when i gave the below command i got error:

gem install json -v 1.8.1

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150908-17724-4ovxaa.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_to_s’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
     VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                               ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
     VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                    ^
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Please someone help me out to fix this. I would really appreciate.